# Why in Helix 3 framework from template disappears webfonts list?

Tags: joomla-3.x, helix3, fonts

I have these kind of errors:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$items in *\plugins\system\helix3\fields\typography.php on line 30
>
> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in *\plugins\system\helix3\fields\typography.php on line 129
>
> Trying to get property of non-object in *\plugins\system\helix3\fields\typography.php on line 75

and something like that more.

Comment: Please try to include more relevant details and use the best English that you can.  I find your question to be Unclear.

Comment: JoomShaper are probably best able to answer this question.

Comment: Ok thanks in advantage. I detected this error while I setting up the google font  list in the schedule " Typography"  joomlashaper template. But not all the helix3 templates in list happens the same error, in fact in the shaper_helix3 - Default one this does not happens. I'am not an expert php user, but I believe could be a possible php bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Helix III framework, Helix author is working on this problem to fix it. Please go to “templates” folder, open your Helix template, find and rename the folder “webfont” to “_webfont”, or just delete it.

[image]

You can see full guides with images via [link](https://enginetemplates.com/solution-for-google-font-problem-from-helix-template-settings-in-joomla-3-9/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insight, but your is Low Quality.  You see, link-only answers are discourages across all site in the Stack Exchange network.  The reason for this is because if the destination page is moved or deleted, then the posted answer is rendered useless forevermore.  Please take a moment to edit your posted answer to flesh out your answer with the advice that resides at the linked page.  Furthermore, when more text is on this page, search engines will have an easier job of directing traffic here.

Comment: Thank you, I just corrected it with more info, picture and link.

Comment: Are you operating two accounts here? It is suspicious the posting and editing times if these two answers.  If you are affiliated with the Helix team, please make this known in your profile.

Answer (score -1):

This is problem with Helix III when you updated Joomla! to 3.9, you can fix it easier, by access your source code via FTP or File Manager, go to folder "templates/[your-helix-template]/", then find folder "webfont" and delete it.

For full guides, you can see it at [here](https://agethemes.com/how-to-fix-google-font-issue-in-helix-template-settings-after-updating-joomla-3-9/).

Comment: Hi @Kelvin Thank you for sharing your insight, but your post has been flagged as (and rightfully so) Low Quality.  You see, link-only answers are discourages across all site in the Stack Exchange network.  The reason for this is because if the destination page is moved or deleted, then the posted answer is rendered useless forevermore.  Please take a moment to edit your posted answer to flesh out your answer with the advice that resides at the linked page.  Furthermore, when more text is on this page, search engines will have an easier job of directing traffic here.